# JavaScript массивы, удаление букв с массива

Tags: javascript

```
let text = ['Привет! Набирай текст', 'Шла Саша по шассе и сосала сушку', 'Кстати, как у тебя дела?'];
```

К примеру, с помощью рандома будет text[0]. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии буквы "П", со слова "Привет" удалялась буква "П" и осталось "ривет! Набирай текст" и так далее.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так

```js
const text = ['Привет! Набирай текст', 'Шла Саша по шассе и сосала сушку', 'Кстати, как у тебя дела?']

const input = document.querySelector('.active')
const answer = document.querySelector('.answer')

answer.value = text[0];

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  const ltr = this.value.slice(-1) // Последняя введенная буква

  // Если последняя введенная буква равна первой букве удаляемого текста
  // тогда удалить, иначе ждать пока введут нужную букву
  if (ltr === answer.value.slice(0, 1)) {
    answer.value = answer.value.slice(1)
  }
})
```

```css
input {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input class="active" type="text">
<br><br>
<input class="answer" type="text" readonly>
```